# Can't Setup Payment Processor

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

When trying to setup a payment processor, I get the error - Access is restricted to CiviDesk users only  Contact CiviDesk for assistance.

What admin role am I missing?

Comment: Ah - you'll need to contact someone from CiviDesk!